# Is $H^1(0,\infty) \subset C^0([0,\infty))$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Is it true that $H^1(0,\infty) \subset C^0([0,\infty))$ is a continuous embedding? How would I prove it?

I do know this holds for bounded domains in one dimension but here we have the half line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Theorem 8.2 in **Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations** by Haim Brezis:

> Let $ u \in W^{1,p}(I)$ with $I$ a bounded or unbounded interval. Then there exists $\tilde u \in C(\bar I)$ with $\tilde u = u$ a.e.  on $I$ and 
>   $$\tilde u(x) - \tilde u(y) = \int_y^x u'$$
>   for all $x, y \in \bar I$.